# Mcrypt error on windows - file was NOT decrypted successfully

Tags: windows, mcrypt

i have browsed for a long time about this issue I can not appear to get something.

i'm using mcrypt on windows 7 I downloaded the the files and use mcrypt from the cmd prompt. NOT USING PHP

I can encrypt allthings good and I can decrypt other file formats .txt .png.. but when it comes to a .mov i find the error "The file " " was NOT decrypted successfully

When I attempt this on my linux system I don't have this issue. It only occurs with windows...? Can somebody please give some insight as to whats going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Since I cant find any answer, I am using 7z for my software.